# Why access app routes prior to creating an app instance

Tags: flask

I was reading up on a Flask example that transitions from a single script application to an application factory and for this reason blueprints are introduced.  The reasoning for using blueprints is because the application instance is now created at runtime instead of existing in the global scope (as it was in the single script application).  This causes the app.route decorator to exist after `create_app()` is invoked, which the book states is too late.  Why is it considered too late for the app.route decorator to exist after `create_app()` is invoked?  Why would we want to access the routes prior to invoking `create_app()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you write an app factory, you don't have an app instance until the factory is called.  The factory is only called when running the server, but you need to define your routes *before* you run the server.  So you attach them to blueprints instead, and register the blueprints on the app in the factory.

```
# this would fail, app doesn't exist
@app.route('/blog/<int:id>')
def post(id):
    ...

# this works because the route is registered on the blueprint
# which is later registered on the app
blog_bp = Blueprint('blog', __name__, url_prefix='/blog')

@blog_bp.route('/<int:id>')
def post(id):
    ...

def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)
    ...
    app.register_blueprint(blog_bp)
    ...
    return app

# app still doesn't exist, it only exists when the server uses the factory
```